# Get primary display in C# is not the same as in Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem understanding how the `Screen.AllScreens[i].Primary` works as it seems for me it messes up the sequence order compared to what I can see in Windows 10 display properties.

In Windows I have two monitors setup like this:

Screen **2** is set as my **Primary**:

[image: Screen 2]

Screen **1**:

[image: Screen 1]

If I then in C# shows the output for both screens in C# *QuickWatch* then I get this:

```
// Get screen parameters
screen2 = Screen.AllScreens[1];
screen1 = Screen.AllScreens[0];
```

Screen **2** (index `1`) is `false` in `Primary`:

[image: Screen 2]

Screen **1** (index `0`) is `true` in `Primary`:

[image: Screen 1]

I can only find one explanation for this - that I cannot trust that what I see in the Windows display properties is the same as the index number I can provide in C#!? That *screen 2 in Windows Display properties* is **not** necessarily the same as *index 1 in C#* but how can I then make this logical to the user - how to collate this information???

My current implementation when using this data - I want it to show "Screen 2" as the primary one:

[image: My screen]

My question can be summaried to:

**How can I show `Screen 2 (Primary)` as this is what I can see also in Windows?**

Comment: The `Screen` class is quite [old](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=net-5.0) going back all the way to .NET 1.1 so it will most likely act different to how you see things enumerated in Windows 10

Comment: I don't know this class, so all I said here is a guess: on your `screen2` you can see the `X` Bound is 1536, that indicates to me that this is the screen more to the rigth. You can also check by changing the resolution of one screen and inspect which one will have the width/heigth modified.

Comment: @Magnetron excellent spot, I had forgotten about that.  Consider posting your comment as an _answer_ below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Bound.X` property to draw to the user the position of each screen. It represents the begining of the screen position. Then, you can name them whatever you want and prompt the user to select the desired one, without reling on Windows naming.

On your `screen2` you can see the `Bound.X` is 1536, that indicates that this is the screen more to the rigth (since the other starts in 0).

Comment: This makes no sense to me - or at least it does not address my problem at all. You can see on my Windows display settings that my screen "2" is the one to the left so it has `X=0`. The next screen is named screen "1" in my Windows display settings but it starts from `X=1536` - so this order is still reversed as I cannot collate what I see on Windows display settings with what I can set myself! in C#? Maybe you misunderstood my question but how can I put "Screen 2 (Primary)" in my application?

Comment: @Beauvais The windows naming is reversed, not the order of the displays. Your `screen1` have the `Bounds.X` set to 0 (the display more to the left) and is the main display, which is the same for the Windows 10 configuration (The display more to the left is the main display) only the naming is different.

Comment: Then what if I have this screen setup in Windows display: 2 => 1 => 3. How will that look like in C#?

Comment: @Beauvais probably you will have a display with `Bounds.X` 0, 1536 and another 3072. Draw on your app theses displays (like with rectangles) and name each one of them. Then, you can prompt your user to select which one they would like to display **based on your naming, not Windows**

Comment: OK, but this is not what I want as there is a lot complexity in this - e.g. you cannot know how the user has physically setup the screens. Simply showing X screens, with primary to the left gives no value for selecting the correct display so I think I am better off just using the standard C# `Screen` method as it will not be any more wrong that what is suggested here.